# Problem with videos on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, video, youtube

I have noticed this particular problem on YouTube and Facebook videos in Ubuntu 15.10(with Google Chrome). The videos play fine on full screen mode but when I try to exit the full screen mode, Ubuntu just hangs(sometimes the audio keeps on playing).

Is any driver update needed? Are there any problems with Flash plug-in?

Answer (score 3):

[Flash is a very CPU intensive application](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1508960&page=2&s=f4f1159ff0d251d42c98cb890e835684) and once the CPU heats, flash performance drops considerably. In your case I believe the problem goes a little further and stops the display of the content.
Also see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1193567

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: Sorry, but only copying and pasting content from other site it is not an accepted answer. Moreover in both link there is no reference to `Google Chrome`. See this link: http://askubuntu.com/help/referencing